# Open SSL certificate fingerprint in C

Tags: certificate, openssl, signing, fingerprint

I am generating a self signed certificate using OpenSSL from C. My code is largely based on the example demo code in the demos/X509 folder (in OpenSSL) and is working ok.

I need to generate a fingerprint of my certificate (and X509 structure) from my C code for later validation, but the OpenSSL documentation is somewhat lacking and I have not managed to work out how to do this. I have searched around for information and all I ever find is how to do it using OpenSSL from the command line.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the openssl crypto APIs to generate the hash. Refer to the openssl crypto documentation at http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html . Below is sample program. Replace the sample text in the following program with your PEM certificate text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EVP_MD_CTX mdctx;
    const EVP_MD *md;
    char mess1[] = "Test Message\n";
    char mess2[] = "Hello World\n";
    unsigned char md_value[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    int md_len, i;

    OpenSSL_add_all_digests();

    if(!argv[1]) {
       printf("Usage: mdtest digestname\n");
       exit(1);
    }

    md = EVP_get_digestbyname(argv[1]);

    if(!md) {
       printf("Unknown message digest %s\n", argv[1]);
       exit(1);
    }

    EVP_MD_CTX_init(&mdctx);
    EVP_DigestInit_ex(&mdctx, md, NULL);
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, mess1, strlen(mess1));
    EVP_DigestUpdate(&mdctx, mess2, strlen(mess2));
    EVP_DigestFinal_ex(&mdctx, md_value, &md_len);
    EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(&mdctx);

    printf("Digest is: ");
    for(i = 0; i < md_len; i++) printf("%02x", md_value[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please forgive my ignorance but I currently have an X509 structure and need to get a fingerprint from that which will be identical to the command line tool. I know I can get the certificate with PEM_Write_X509 but this gives me formatting (------BEGIN CERTIFICATE---- etc). Is there an easy way to get at just the certificate data.

Comment: Yes. The PEM certificate text begins with the '---BEGIN CERTIFICATE--' phrase. This is the standard base64 encoded format. The PEM certficate text contains all the information of the certificate and you should use this text to calculate the hash.

Comment: You can very well use other binary forms of the certificates as well. Handling PEM format is a bit simpler but you can choose the format as per your interest.

Answer (score 9):

When you already have an X509 structure it is possible to just use X509_digest(...) on the X509 structure as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749567/2131459

```
const EVP_MD *digest = EVP_get_digestbyname("sha1");
X509_digest(x, digest, buff, &n);
```

Additionally, the X509 structure even has a member called sha1_hash (if openSSL has been compiled with SHA support). However I do not know whether this property can be used safely or some action has to be taken.

(Sorry for digging out this old topic but it was the first hit on google when looking for openssl fingerprint.)

Comment: Upvoted.. and /headdesk. I can't believe I just implemented a whole bunch of code to do this very simple thing.   I used `BIO_f_md()` and `i2d_X509_bio` though, which were simpler than the `EVP_MD_CTX` approach also posted here.

Comment: you may need to load all digests using `OpenSSL_add_all_digests()` before calling `EVP_get_digestbyname`

Comment: You can get the `EVP_MD *digest` object directly by calling `EVP_sha1()` or `EVP_sha256()`.